# Need to send custom XML structure over SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis

I'm using Apache Axis2 and need to send a custom XML structure over SOAP to clients.  So basically client will make a request and the client will expect the response to be as an XML representation.

What would be the best way to do this?

Should I create a Java object to represent the XML structure and then have Apache Axis2 do the serialization for sending to SOAP? I guess the client side will need to know how to deserialize this complex type, correct?

Should I just create a String representation of this XML structure and send it over SOAP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in more maintainable and reliable code the object route is definitely the way to go.